# Python error for request.get

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a Python script which enables me to acces a webpage and download a file from that page. My first attempt was to simply get to that page and i tried the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' #using google as an example

r = requests.get(url)

print(r.url)
```

I am given this error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TMS502.py', wdir='C:/Users/ME/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-bc585dcceef8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TMS502.py', wdir='C:/Users/ME/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TMS502.py", line 16, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?gws_rd=ssl (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because the remote side (in this case Google) is closing your requests or you are otherwise no longer able to establish a connection to it.

From the error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /?gws_rd=ssl 
(Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

We can look into the [source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/8b5e457b756b2ab4c02473f7a42c2e0201ecc7e9/requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py#L62-L78) for a hint:

```
class MaxRetryError(RequestError):
    """Raised when the maximum number of retries is exceeded.
    :param pool: The connection pool
    :type pool: :class:`~urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool`
    :param string url: The requested Url
    :param exceptions.Exception reason: The underlying error
    """

    def __init__(self, pool, url, reason=None):
        self.reason = reason

        message = "Max retries exceeded with url: %s (Caused by %r)" % (
            url, reason)

        RequestError.__init__(self, pool, url, message)
```

Try another example host and your code should work, such as https://example.org.

The error message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" is coming from your operating system (Windows) and Requests is showing you this text in an attempt to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

I guess the problem is coursed by `url = 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl'`.

Maybe your network can't reach `www.google.com`, try another url.

Answer (score -3):

y are you bothering with requests anyway:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
u = urlopen("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl")
data = u.read()
u.close()
```

Maybe this'll work.

Comment: Now I get: <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>

Comment: I think this is occurring because of the setup for my computer at my company and I might be need to be passing some sort of password validation screen for this to work.

Comment: Hm, interesting! If what you say is true, then two things I can think of now are: 1. Does your webbrowser work, and are there any HTTP proxies configured on your PC. If there are proxies, you'll need to pass additional info either to urllib or requests so that they use this proxy. And 2. Perhaps firewall blocks HTTP requests not made by a browser. In that case you can fool it.

Comment: To do it with urllib: r = Request("http://..."); r.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 compatible;"); u = urlopen(r); etc. etc. Maybe it won't still work and you'll have to supply a fuller User-Agent to emulate one of existing web browsers. But I dislike doing it. Feels illegal. (dont forget import Request from urllib2)

Comment: Someone got offended with thought that something might not work in ipython, so I edited the post. I see nobody else has anything clever to offer.

Comment: @Dalen why are you criticizing the asker for his choice of libraries without understanding why the error is happening?

Comment: @tristan : I criticize nobody! Requests is convoluted in attempt to do stuff better and easier. So, sometimes is harder to see where the error comes from. That's why I recomended urllib instead. I can see from your answer that you have no better idea. I don't assume that OP is so stupid that he didn't try other URL instead of Google.  I think my comment about proxies or firewall still has some value.

Comment: @Dalen "I can see from your answer that you have no better idea."  Actually, I answered the question.  Your follow-ups asking for proxy and firewall information are comments and not answers.

Comment: @tristan : And  what is your answer? Try another host! I am sure he did that already! I'll edit my post to answer the Q completely after OP says that he has proxy or filter. Or won't if he doesn't.

Comment: Did the OP say he tried another host?  No.  Beyond explaining why the error is happening, my answer only shows where it comes from in the source, explains how his OS comes into it, and offers an explicit solution, so you're right: my answer and your "y are you bothering with requests" answer are about that same.

Comment: P.S. See, OS cannot know whether the socket was closed by a remote host or a firewall bbefore reaching the end point for instance. The connection is closed and that is that. But usually the connection isn't permitted at all if this is the case. And, what if ipython has some issues with SSL CA's? The comment above makes me think that this is strictly a network problem. Google may close the connection if Google doesn't like User-Agent, but most sites shouldn't do it. I still believe OP tried more URLs